# 3D surface plot using Tikz, overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am looking for hints or help on how to fix the following:

I am trying to get a nice-looking 3D surface plot of a parametrization of a part of a sphere. This is a MWE of it:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view = {30}{30}, % I already tried different angles for the first value like 30,60,150,210,300, the picture changes, but there's always the same issue
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    xmin=-1,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=1,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=1.5,
    grid=major,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
]

\addplot3 [
    colormap/viridis,
    domain=1/6*pi:1/2*pi, %I already tried the domain defined in reverse, or defined like on wikipedia from 0 to 1/3*pi, and the result did change, but it didn't fix the issue
    y domain=3/6*pi:15/6*pi, %I already tried so many different angles here, starting at anything in between 0 and 2*pi and doing one full rotation. The picture changes but I can't seem to get rid of the issue
    surf,
    shader=interp,
    samples=40,
    opacity=1.0, %Ideally I want opacity=0.9 but even with opacity=1.0 or commenting out this line the issue persists
] (
    {1*cos(deg(x))*cos(deg(y))},
    {1*cos(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))},
    {1*sin(deg(x))}
);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of this can be seen here: [image: Weird backside see-through on 3D surface plot]

Unfortunately, there seems to be some weird see-through of the backside of the surface, which makes it look really awkward. Does anyone know how to get rid of this? I wrote into the code (using comments) what I already tried but I can't seem to get it to work. For sake of easy reading, here's a list what I tried:

1. already tried different view angles like 30,60,150,210,300, the picture changes, but there's always the same issue
2. I already tried the theta domain (here: x) defined in reverse, or defined like on wikipedia from 0 to 1/3*pi, and the result did change, but it didn't fix the issue
3. I already tried so many different angles for the phi domain (here: y), starting at anything in between 0 and 2*pi and doing one full rotation. The picture changes but I can't seem to get rid of the issue
4. Ideally I want opacity=0.9 but even with opacity=1.0 or commenting out this line the issue persists

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!